# Searching between TreeView Nodes Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

**TLDR: Use treeview to search network folders and show results in trees path.**

I have a tool at work that is outdated and needs to be updated, but the source was lost, so I have been rebuilding it. This is the only thing I am struggling with recreating.

In Powershell ISE having a Tree View be searchable, that updates with $textbox.add_textchanged as you type to find matched text.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
function Product-Function{
$Product.add_textchanged{
#idk what im doing
                        }
                         }

$Product                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Product.multiline                = $false
$Product.CharacterCasing          = "Upper"
$Product.width                    = 235
$Product.height                   = 20
$Product.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)
$Product.Font                     = $MainFont
$Product.Text                     = ""
Product-Function

$TreeView                         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$TreeView.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 55)
$TreeView.Size                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(540, 320)

$WinNode                          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinNode.text                     = "Windows"
$WinNode.name                     = "Windows"
[void]$TreeView.Nodes.Add($WinNode).FullPath

$WinCommonNode                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinCommonNode.text               = "Common"
$WinCommonNode.name               = "Common"
[void]$WinNode.Nodes.Add($WinCommonNode)

$WinCommonNCNode                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinCommonNCNode.text             = "Non_Certified"
$WinCommonNCNode.name             = "Non_Certified"
[void]$WinCommonNode.Nodes.Add($WinCommonNCNode)

$WinLicensedNode                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinLicensedNode.text             = "Licensed"
$WinLicensedNode.name             = "Licensed"
[void]$WinNode.Nodes.Add($WinLicensedNode)

$WinLicensedNCNode                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinLicensedNCNode.text           = "Non_Certified"
$WinLicensedNCNode.name           = "Non_Certified"
[void]$WinLicensedNode.Nodes.Add($WinLicensedNCNode)

$WinRestrictedNode                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinRestrictedNode.text           = "Restricted"
$WinRestrictedNode.name           = "Restricted"
[void]$WinNode.Nodes.Add($WinRestrictedNode)

$WinRestrictedNCNode              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WinRestrictedNCNode.text         = "Non_Certified"
$WinRestrictedNCNode.name         = "Non_Certified"
[void]$WinRestrictedNode.Nodes.Add($WinRestrictedNCNode)


#macs

$MacNode                          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$MacNode.text                     = "Macaroni"
$MacNode.name                     = "Macaroni"
$Macaroni                         = "\\NetworkLocation\Macintosh"
[void]$TreeView.Nodes.Add($MacNode).FullPath

#=======================================================================================================================
                                                  #File Paths#
#=======================================================================================================================
$WinCommon = "\\NetworkLocation\DesktopServices\Common"
$WinLicensed = "\\NetworkLocation\DesktopServices\Licensed"
$WinRestricted = "\\NetworkLocation\DesktopServices\Restricted"
$WinCommonNC = "\\NetworkLocation\DesktopServices\Common\_Non-Certified"
$WinLicensedNC = "\\NetworkLocation\DesktopServices\Licensed\_Non-Certified"
$WinRestrictedNC = "\\NetworkLocation\DesktopServices\Restricted\_Non-Certified"

#=======================================================================================================================

$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $WinCommon)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$WCNode                           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WCNode.text                      = $obj
[void]$WinCommonNode.Nodes.Add($WCNode).FullPath
     }
$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $WinLicensed)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$WLNode                           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WLNode.text                      = $obj
[void]$WinLicensedNode.Nodes.Add($WLNode).FullPath
     }
$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $WinRestricted)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$WRNode                           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WRNode.text                      = $obj
[void]$WinRestrictedNode.Nodes.Add($WRNode).FullPath
     }

$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $WinCommonNC)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$WCNCNode                         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WCNCNode.text                    = $obj
[void]$WinCommonNCNode.Nodes.Add($WCNCNode).FullPath
     }
$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $WinLicensedNC)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$WLNCNode                         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WLNCNode.text                    = $obj
[void]$WinLicensedNCNode.Nodes.Add($WLNCNode).FullPath
     }
$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $WinRestrictedNC)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$WRNCNode                         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$WRNCNode.text                    = $obj
[void]$WinRestrictedNCNode.Nodes.Add($WRNCNode).FullPath
     }

     #mac stuff

$array                            = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $Macaroni)
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {
$SubMac                           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$SubMac.text                      = $obj
[void]$MacNode.Nodes.Add($SubMac).FullPath
     }
#=======================================================================================================================
```

**So my question is, How can I make my textbox filter all of the items within nodes, for match namees, and show where it is within the nodes**

The reason we have this tool, is we have hundreds of software installs in these folders and this tool makes it easy to search for the exact location. It was made in the past and I just need to remake it, but I can not figure out how to filter the pulled data of the nodes.

================== Everything above has been answered.

Additional question.
Is there a way to hide extra non matched items and shrink nodes that do not have any matches. Our old tool does, and it makes it way easier to read the location.
[image]

old tool on the left, my new tool on the right.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask your question :)

Comment: Damn, my b. Brain is fried from trying to figure this out. I just have no idea where to start on getting it to search items within all nodes. Updated OP

Comment: Bottom-up level-order traversal of the tree, skip any ancestors of leaf nodes not matching the search term - rebuilt filtered tree from that. Hopefully that at least gets you something to google :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the node having text like *razer*?

Comment: that was just an example, the current tool lets you type anything and as you type it searchs. So if I type "Chr" it will find things that have that and probably show "Google Chrome" , or if I type "Micro" it will show all things that have "Microsoft" in their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive method to get all nodes or search between all nodes and return the first occurrence of a text in nodes:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function GetNodes([System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection] $nodes)
{
     foreach ($n in $nodes) {
        $n
        GetNodes($n.Nodes)
     }
}

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text ="Test"
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
    ($txt = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{
        Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(8, 8);
        Width = 100;
    }),
    ($btn = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{
        Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(120, 8);
        Width = 50;
        Text = "Search";
    }),
    ($tree = [System.Windows.Forms.TreeView] @{
        Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(8, 40);
        Width = 170;
        HideSelection = $false
    })
))
$form.AcceptButton= $btn

$tree.Nodes.Add("A1", "A1")
$tree.Nodes.Add("A2", "A2")
$tree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("A11", "A11")
$tree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("A12", "A12")
$tree.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("A21", "A21")
$tree.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("A22", "A22")

$btn.Add_Click({param($sender,$e)
    $nodes = GetNodes($tree.Nodes)
    foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        if($node.Text -like $txt.Text){
            $tree.SelectedNode = $node
            $node.EnsureVisible()
            break
        }
     }
})
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: This might be exactly what I am looking for, I am going to test it, add it to my code, and will get back to you if it works for me. Thank you so so much for the feed back.

Comment: This worked BEAUTIFULLY FOR ME. It will take a bit to edit into my code, but i got it to work with text change, and not need to press a search button. Thank you so much, the amount of headache you saved me can never be repaid.

Comment: You're welcome :) `TextChange` also works. JFYI, in the example I've set the button as default button, so you don't need to click it, you just need to press enter.

Comment: One last thing, is there a way to hide all the extra pulls. This scrolls down the list to show the searched one, is there a way to hide anything that doesnt meet the -match property?

Comment: added a picture to my OP for more details of what I am aiming for.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1000621/Filtering-and-Hiding-Tree-Nodes-WinForms 
I found this, but this does not work in powershell, but the result is what I am looking for. I have tried using If and Else statments for selected nodes.